# scheme and if condition

Tags: scheme, if-statement

I want to return nothing when if condition is not met, for instance

```
(if x y z)
```

so if x is not met, z will be executed and I want to do nothing at z, just same as pythons "pass"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [R5RS](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_idx_98):

> syntax:  `(if test consequent alternate)`
>
> syntax:  `(if test consequent)`
>
> Semantics: An `if` expression is
>   evaluated as follows: first, *test* is
>   evaluated. If it yields a true value
>   (see section 6.3.1), then *consequent*
>   is evaluated and its value(s) is(are)
>   returned. Otherwise *alternate* is
>   evaluated and its value(s) is(are)
>   returned. **If *test* yields a false
>   value and no *alternate* is specified,
>   then the result of the expression is
>   unspecified.**

So your `if` expression becomes:

```
(if x y)
```

Comment: Note that one-branched if expressions are considered bad in PLT, and in fact they're not allowed in the default language.  If you want it there, use `when` or `unless`.

Comment: I actually tested it in PLT Scheme using R5RS language before posting, and it works without a problem.

Comment: Yes, the r5rs language in PLT is pretty strict about following the report.  Whether using one-sided `if`s is a good idea is a different question...

Comment: In my experience, using `when` and `unless` is much better form for one-branch conditionals, as you don't need to wrap multi-statement bodies in a `(begin ...)`. If your scheme does not have them, they are trivial to write.

Comment: Listen to Eli : ) I had a long discussion with Eli about this and I have to agree that having a one sided if statement could be explosive.

Comment: It's because of undefined behaviour that the second type of if may not work. Undefined means implementation-defined, so to be safe, I would use `(if test consequent #f)`

Comment: @omouse What do you mean 'may not work'? It's not the *behaviour* that is undefined, it's the *result*.